# need to download pdf file in client machine using itext pdf

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, itext

i am using itext pdf to generate my pdf and that is saved correctly in server but that should be downloaded(saved)in client side. i called method to generate pdf from jsp page.
here is my code:

```
 calling:
  Document b = new JavaPdfHelloWorld().Generate_pdf(con.getCon(), file_no, pdt);

 definition:
         public class JavaPdfHelloWorld {
           public Document Generate_pdf(Connection con, String file_no, PensionDataDao pdt) throws IOException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    System.out.println(home);
    File file = new File(home + "/Downloads/dcrg-diff/" + name_of_pensioner + " " + space + " "
                    + updated_file_no + ".pdf");
   FileOutputStream pdfFileout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfFileout);
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("CALCULATION SHEET AS PER GRATUITY ACT 1972",
                    FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED)));

            document.close();
            writer.close();

   return document;
```

Comment: Then don't write to the server, but the outputstream of the response.

Comment: @M.Deinum please give some example... how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the **FileOutputStream** into **Response** object instead of just returning the **document**. Along with that you also need to set **Content-Type** of Response to **"application/pdf"**.

Comment: do i need to use servlet ? actually i'm new in development . so kindly tell me how to do this . as i m calling a method generate_pdf from a jsp page.